# Why does Fortran based MPI routine take more compute time when more processes are launched

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

My Fortran based MPI code does not involve communication among processes. Only computation by each process, is done and timed. My platform is Intel Sandy Bridge. The code is compiled using mpiifort wrapper. I have two observations that I cannot explain:

1) Computation time increases as more machines are involved, where each machine has 16 cores (2 processors, 8 cores per processor). For example, 16 MPI ranks took 5.74 seconds at most, 32 took 13.64, 48 took 18.26 seconds, whereas 64 took 25.92 seconds. Since no communication is involved, I was expecting to get about the same timings irrespective of how name MPI ranks are launched. The code is included below.

2) Inside Step 2 of the code below, a subroutine is called. If I replace the subroutine call with the actual code, the program runs way faster. For example, 16 MPI ranks took 5.63E-02 seconds at most, 32 took 0.1762, 48 took 0.33 seconds, whereas 64 took 0.3612 seconds.

A serial version of the program compiled with ifort also exhibits similar behavior: with the subroutine call it takes 0.77 seconds and without takes 5.19E-02 seconds.

I am attaching the code here. First is without subroutine call, second is with subroutine call, and third is the subroutine itself.

mult.f (no subroutine call):

```
  program mul
  include 'mpif.h'

  integer DIM, dim1, dim2, dim3, E
  parameter (DIM=8, E=512, dim1=DIM, dim2=DIM, dim3=DIM)
  integer ierr, rank, size, t2, t4, t6, t8
  real*8 A(dim1, dim1), B(dim2, dim2), C(dim3, dim3)
  real*8 u(dim1, dim2, dim3, E)
  real*8 dudr (dim1, dim2, dim3, E), duds (dim1, dim2, dim3, E)
  real*8 dudt (dim1, dim2, dim3, E), dudr2 (dim1, dim2, dim3)
  integer val, i, j, k, l, r, s, t, start, end
  integer iseed /3/
  real tbeg, tend
  CHARACTER(len=32) :: arg

  call getarg(1, arg)
  call MPI_INIT (ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

  ! Step 1: Initialize
  do i = 1, dim1
       do j = 1, dim1
           A (i, j) = ran(iseed);
       enddo
  enddo

  do i = 1, dim2
       do j = 1, dim2
           B (i, j) = A(j, i);
       enddo
  enddo

  do i = 1, dim3
       do j = 1, dim3
           C (i, j) = A(j, i);
       enddo
  enddo

  do m = 1, E
  do i=1, dim1
        do j=1, dim2
              do k = 1, dim3
                     u (i, j, k, m) = (ran(iseed)*400.0) - 200.0
                  enddo
        enddo
  enddo
  enddo

  ! Step 2: Compute derivatives
  tbeg = mpi_wtime()

  do m = 0, 5000
      do ie=1, E
         DO t2=1,8
         DO t4=1,8
         DO t6=1,8
         DO t8=1,8
             dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie) = 0
             dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)=dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)+u(t2,t4,t6,ie)
 $                             *C(t8,t2)
         ENDDO
         DO t8=1,8
             dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)=dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)
 $                             +u(t2,t4,t6,ie)*C(t8,t2)

         ENDDO
         ENDDO
         ENDDO
         ENDDO
      enddo
  enddo
  tend = mpi_wtime()
  print *, DIM, E, tend-tbeg, rank

  call MPI_FINALIZE (ierr)

  end
```

mult.f (with subroutine)

```
  program mul
  include 'mpif.h'

  integer DIM, dim1, dim2, dim3, E
  parameter (DIM=8, E=512, dim1=DIM, dim2=DIM, dim3=DIM)
  integer ierr, rank, size
  real*8 A(dim1, dim1), B(dim2, dim2), C(dim3, dim3)
  real*8 u(dim1, dim2, dim3, E)
  real*8 dudr (dim1, dim2, dim3, E), duds (dim1, dim2, dim3, E)
  real*8 dudt (dim1, dim2, dim3, E), dudr2 (dim1, dim2, dim3)
  integer val, i, j, k, l, r, s, t, start, end
  integer iseed /3/
  real tbeg, tend
  CHARACTER(len=32) :: arg

  call getarg(1, arg)
  call MPI_INIT (ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

  ! Step 1: Initialize
  do i = 1, dim1
       do j = 1, dim1
           A (i, j) = ran(iseed);
       enddo
  enddo

  do i = 1, dim2
       do j = 1, dim2
           B (i, j) = A(j, i);
       enddo
  enddo

  do i = 1, dim3
       do j = 1, dim3
           C (i, j) = A(j, i);
       enddo
  enddo

  do m = 1, E
  do i=1, dim1
        do j=1, dim2
              do k = 1, dim3
                     u (i, j, k, m) = (ran(iseed)*400.0) - 200.0
                  enddo
        enddo
  enddo
  enddo

  ! Step 2: Compute derivatives
  tbeg = mpi_wtime()

  do m = 0, 5000
      do ie=1, E
         call mysubroutine(u, C, dudr, ie)
      enddo
  enddo
  tend = mpi_wtime()
  print *, DIM, E, tend-tbeg, rank

  call MPI_FINALIZE (ierr)

  end
```

mysubroutine (subroutine call):

```
   SUBROUTINE mysubroutine(u, a, dudr, ie)
   integer DIM, dim1, dim2, dim3, E
   parameter (DIM=8, E=512, dim1=DIM, dim2=DIM, dim3=DIM)
   real*8 u(DIM, DIM, DIM, E)
   real*8 a(DIM, DIM)
   real*8 dudr (DIM, DIM, DIM, E)
     integer t8
     integer t6
     integer t4
     integer t2
     integer i
     integer j
     integer k
     integer l
   !dir$ ASSUME_ALIGNED a:    64
   !dir$ ASSUME_ALIGNED u:    64
   !dir$ ASSUME_ALIGNED dudr: 64
     DO t2=1,8
     DO t4=1,8
     DO t6=1,8
     DO t8=1,8
     dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)
 $     =0
     dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)=dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)+u(t2,t4,t6,ie)
 $     *a(t8,t2)
   ENDDO
     DO t8=1,8
     dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)=dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)
 $     +u(t2,t4,t6,ie)*a(t8,t2)
   ENDDO
   ENDDO
   ENDDO
   ENDDO
   END
```

The code is compiled using the following command:

```
mpiifort -O3 -mcmodel=large -xavx mult.f rose.f -o baseline
```

Comment: Where do you ever send or receive any messages in that program?  Where’s the parallelism?

Comment: If you stick it all in the program the optimiser might be able to work out that as dudr is never referenced after the loops it can just totally optimise away the loop structure, this is much more difficult if a subroutine is called. What happens if you write dudr to a file at the end of the program? Oh, and please drag your fortran out of the 1980s. At the very least please use implicit none. MPI problems might be due to memory bandwidth issues on 1 node, and wrong process placement on multiples. Are you sure all the processes are not on 1 node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distinct questions here:

1. Why is the code with subroutine call slower; and
2. Why is the code slower as the number of MPI processes increases.

I'll try to answer (with wild guesses I must admit) to both of them in sequence.

**subroutine slower**

If you look at your code, you'll see that in order to increase the time taken to compute, you enclosed your actual computation into a `m` loop of 5001 iterations. But if you look at your actual computation, you'll see that, although you indeed use your `dudr` array to update it, you always start with `dudr(t8,t4,t6,ie)=0`. So its previous value is irrelevant since you erase it. Therefore, only the last iteration of the `m` loop has any effect...

But in order to the compiler to see that, it needs to see the body of the routine. So by calling a subroutine, you force the compiler to actually do something 5001 times, whereas by inlining it, you give it the opportunity to realise it is pointless and that only one iteration does the trick!

Well, this is mostly speculations of mine, but I've seen that so many times that I'm confident I'm not far from the truth. Indeed, since you subsequently do nothing with `dudr`, I'm even surprised that the compiler generates anything at all out of your big loop...

**More MPI processes takes longer**

Well for this one, I'll make an even wilder guess: I believe that somehow, instead of submitting in several nodes, you actually submitted by mistake your code on one single node. And there, the many MPI processes competed to access the resources (the memory bandwidth notably), and took longer and longer as the number of processes increased... I might be wrong, but at the moment, this is the est explanation I have.

**A word of wisdom**

When you try to benchmark performance, make sure to always hide to the compiler that you are not interested by the actual result of a computation. This can be done by printing some values, or passing it to an external routine (possibly doing nothing, but the compiler won't know that). Otherwise, you might get surprised on how *clever* it can get and how much it can remove of *dead code*.

Comment: Thanks again for your insightful answer. I think you nailed both of them. I will do some further experiments and will post the findings.

Comment: I was using mpirun instead of srun on this cluster. So with srun, I am not seeing the issue of more MPI processes take longer, anymore. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Further, I added the external routine to my code. Timing did not change, but your advice is well taken.